# Is it possible to call the Run Window with a command in Windows?

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, run-dialog

I am wondering if it is possible to call the run window either from CMD, PowerShell, or using VBScript, etc. with a command/app/directory to run?

I know that `explorer.exe Shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}` exists and that run is not it's own standalone app (sad) but can I take commands to it?

Maybe a solution to open it and then type it out really fast using a program/script, but is there something like `cmd /c` for run?

Comment: What's your final goal? What do you want to achieve by calling the Run window?

Comment: powershell: `(New-Object -ComObject "Shell.Application").FileRun()

`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53111397/how-to-open-the-run-dialog-box-with-a-file-already-in-the-box

Comment: Please answer question from @SaaruLindestøkke .. this all seems pointless.  Please let us know what the purpose is so that we all might learn.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I am trying to create a fluent style run window, but it seems pointless to recode run from scratch if I can call it with a command / arguments, and I mean to supply run with a file etc. to run, not just open the window, that I know how to do.

Comment: With a fluent style run window, do you mean something like powertoys run? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/run

Comment: not exactly, I mean something like [this concept](https://www.reddit.com/r/Windows_Redesign/comments/siymnw/fluent_run_window_and_dialogs_made_with_uwp/hw7hljc/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want a commandline version of the Run window, the easy solution is the `start` utility:

```
start https://www.google.com
start %APPDATA%
cmd /c start appname://open/foo
```

Or to truly emulate Run, you can use the exact (C++) function that Run uses: [ShellExecute()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/launch)

---

On the other hand, if you want to "open it and then type it out really fast", then you could try a basic sendkeys script:

```sh
# powershell
using namespace microsoft.VisualBasic
using namespace System.Windows.Forms

# open Run window
cmd /c 'explorer.exe Shell:::{2559a1f3-21d7-11d4-bdaf-00c04f60b9f0}'
start-sleep -Milliseconds 500

# type out a command 
[Interaction]::AppActivate(“Run”)
[SendKeys]::SendWait('{%}APPDATA{%}')
```